# Get GeoLocation and Subscribe to Service Angular2+

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps

I am getting user's geoLocation using google map api, retrieving the lat & lng info. I want to pass the lat, lng to a web api service and get the json output of surrounding addresses. For getting data from web api service, i am using angular2 code that works fine.

Below is code for details:

```
data.service.ts file:
fetchData(lat: number, lng: number) {
    return this._http.get('/url?lat=' + lat + '&lon=' + lng)
        .map((response: Response) => response.json());
}


app.component.ts
```

ngOnInit(){

```
var lat;
    var lng;

    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
            lat = position.coords.latitude;
            lng = position.coords.longitude;

        });

if ((lat != null) && (lng != null)) {


this._dataService.fetchData(lat, lng).subscribe(res => {
        this.dObj = res;
    });
}
}
```

The above code doesn't work. I tried to play around with the code. fetchData() gets called before (i believe since its async) and somehow i am unable to pass the lat, lng to the service.

Is there a proper way to achieve this? What are the other ways to do this? Are there any angular2 libraries that does similar things that i can use? Please help

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should put all your logic inside the callback function of the `getCurrentPosition()`. Indeed the HTML5 geolocation is async, so it looks like you try to retrieve the `lat` and `lng` before the callback happened.

Try this

```
var lat;
var lng;

if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition( position => {
        lat = position.coords.latitude;
        lng = position.coords.longitude;

        if ((lat != null) && (lng != null)) {

            this._dataService.fetchData(lat, lng).subscribe(res => {
                this.dObj = res;
            });
        }
    });
}
```